# Restore Primary Display in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: multiple-monitors, display

I change my primary display on external LCD for a bigger monitor in the office. After going back home, I found that my laptop primary display is still on the external LCD. The "set primary display" option is gone when I'm not connected to an external LCD monitor.

Can I change primary display option from anywhere else other than Displays Settings?